# What are the implications of not tracking the url.path in StormCrawler?

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

We're using [StormCrawler](http://stormcrawler.net/) and storing our `Status` index in elasticsearch. This index is getting pretty big (almost 3 billion docs!) and so the shards are also big to backup etc.

I'm considering removing the `url.path` metadata array element in the docs. [It looks like](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/wiki/Configuration#metadata) I can disable it with `metadata.track.path`.

What are the implications if I were to no longer index this and delete what I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not interested in tracking how a particular URL has been found then yes, you'd save space (and a bit of time) by setting *metadata.track.path* to false. You can do that straight away and any new documents won't have the corresponding field.

Not sure what you mean by 'delete what I have' - you can't delete just one field, you'd have to delete and reindex the whole documents.

As a rule, make sure you index only the fields you need. See [this customised version of the ES index init script](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/stormcrawlerfight/blob/es6%2Bwarc/ES_IndexInit.sh#L20) where 'hostname' has been moved out of the fields prefixed with metadata in order to be searchable. The options available depend on the version of Elasticsearch that you are using.